# Split or Extract Strings into Arguments of Function?

Tags: python, string

I have a function that accepts multiple arguments. I can call it like:

```
i_take_strings('one', 'two', 'and_the_letter_C')
```

But suppose I want to determine the arguments dynamically, for example, by splitting a string. I tried:

```
s = 'one two and_the_letter_c'
    
i_take_strings(x for x in s.split())
```

but I get an error message. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: i_take_string(*tuple([x for x in s.split()])) would do, what you do is creating a generator, not a list.

Comment: @mission.liao code would work but could be simplified to `i_take_strings(*s.split())`. See [Pass list to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961007/passing-an-array-list-into-python) for more

Comment: Python should not think you're retarded. You just tell it to pass an generator to the function - and python will do just that without questioning your mental health.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s.split()` already returns a list so you can pass it to your function as [`variable arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) by prepending `*` like follows:

```
i_take_strings(*s.split())
```

Comment: Very nice. Today I learned something new in Python. Rejoice with me.