# Pass string as tuple as arguments python

Tags: python, arguments, tuples

If I have a string like:

```
"spam, foo, moo"
```

How would I pass that to a function so it would turn into:

```
myFunction("spam", "moo", "foo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string to list of things:

```
your_string = "spam, foo, moo"
your_function(*your_string.split(', '))
```

Comment: Can you pass a list for arguments? I thought that you could only pass a tuple.

Comment: Just tested in my interpreter - you can. Thanks!

Comment: Of course. @DennysBlake for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961007/passing-an-array-list-into-python

Comment: Just a note : your answer was wrong at first and you modified it after I wrote mine. I'll have better luck next time!

Comment: @DennysBlake Fixed.

Comment: They should also be your in the code, and it should be a "list of strings". Sorry that I'm making you do this, I can't edit your post.

Comment: @DennysBlake no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string and [unpack the elements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), in order to get 3 arguments.

With just split, you'd get one argument, a list of 3 strings.

```
myFunction(*"spam, foo, moo".split(', '))
```