# Using type hints on an array function input

Tags: python

I recently read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961007/passing-an-array-list-into-a-python-function) which talks about using an array as a function input, and was just wondering if it was possible to use type hints to hint that the array is meant to be an array of `str`?

for example:

```
def sterileInput(options = []) -> str:
                          # ^ I want to hint that this array contains strings
    pass
```

Comment: Do you want `sterileInput(options: list[str])`?

Comment: What is shown here is **not a type hint**, but a default value for the parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `typing` module

```
from typing import List
def sterileInput(options: List[str]) -> str:
    pass
```