# Returning list as integer gives TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, error-handling, solver, git-checkout

```
sum = []
def s(d):
    d = list[int]
    sum = []
    for i in d:
        sum += i
        return(sum)
s([1, 2, 3])
```

Python gives me the following message:
`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable.`

How can I make the code work?

Answer (score 1):

1. As first commentator said, you are iterating a list composed of one element: a type `int` (which is not iterable, as the error message states). If you trying to specify a type of argument `d` in your function, you should use code like that:

```py
def s(d: list[int]):
   ...
```

2. Also if you trying to find a sum of elements in list, you should define `sum = 0` instead of `sum = []`.
3. Your return statement is not fully correct - write `return sum` instead of `return(sum)`, because `return` is not a function.

Comment: You forgot to add that the indentation of the `return` statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating a list composed of one element: a type '`int`' (which is not iterable, as the error message states)

You can use instead a [list as parameter of your function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63511233/6309), and remove the `d = list[int]` list.

```py
def sumlist(d=[]):
```